# Checking string with custom format in c#

Tags: c#

I'm creating a command system for my application but i don't know how to make c# recognize a pattern in my string.

Example:

> add(variable1, variable2)

How to make c# recognize `addUser(...)` and do some stuff?

I'm currently using string contains but if user type `add()()()()()` or `add((((((`, it still work!

Please help!

sorry about my english!

Comment: Your question is very unclear to me, please clarify.

Comment: You may be able to use Regular Expressions, but we really need to know what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: Looks like you want to parse the input string. Are you looking to create some sort of scripting language? What sort of expressions do you want to support? Only function calls?

Comment: ok! i want to add user with name abc to database by type command to a textbox like "addUser(abc)". What i'm trying to do right now is:    if string contain "addUser" so add user to database. The problem is if i type "addUser-----adfasdf", it still work because it contain "addUser".    What i want is the program recognize the specific format "addUser(...)" (with 2 parentheses) and add variable in these parentheses to database?

Comment: Please be more specific. It is expected that you will try _something_ and then ask for help, providing [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows clearly what you've tried, as well as precise explanation of what that code does and how that's different from what you want. There are far too many possible ways to answer the question as it's stated now.

Comment: You can try to read [.NET Regular Expressions: Regex and Balanced Matching](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2005/03/15/396452.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This may not be perfect, but might give you some ideas :)

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string example_input = "xxxxx Add(user1, user2) xxxxxx";
        string myArgs = getBetween2(example_input, "Add(", ")"); //myArgs = "user1, user2"

        if (myArgs != "EMPTY")
        {
            myArgs = myArgs.Replace(" ", ""); // remove spaces... myArgs = "user1,user2"
            string[] userArray = myArgs.Split(',');

            foreach (string user in userArray)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(user);

                //Your code here
            }
        }

        Console.ReadKey(); //pause
    }

    static string getBetween2(string strSource, string strStart, string strEnd)
    {
        try
        {
            int Start, End;
            if (strSource.Contains(strStart) && strSource.Contains(strEnd))
            {
                Start = strSource.IndexOf(strStart, 0) + strStart.Length;
                End = strSource.IndexOf(strEnd, Start);
                return strSource.Substring(Start, End - Start);
            }
            else
            {
                return "EMPTY";
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return "EMPTY";
        }
    }
```